# Converges or diverges: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left [\arctan{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}+{(-1)^n\over n^2}\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How can I show that the following series converges or diverges ?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left [\arctan{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}+{(-1)^n\over n^2}\right]$$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left [\arctan{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}\right]+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[{(-1)^n\over n^2}\right]$, for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[{(-1)^n\over n^2}\right]$ I used Leibniz criteria, by showing that $1\over n^2$ is decreasing and its limit is zero, thus the series converges. For $\arctan...$ the first series I thought to use the same Leibniz criteria, because $1\over n$ is decreasing to zero, but I do not know, is it right to say that if ${(-1)^n \over n}$ decreases then $\left [\arctan{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}\right]$ also decreases  ? Is it right what I did ? Thank you.

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, what do you can conclude?

Comment: That its increasing for any x ?

Comment: Leibniz criteria requires $a_n > 0$ and $a_n \to 0$ for the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$, so yes it converges, for $a_n = \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{n}$ as it $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @sciona so $arctan...$ series converges, yes ?

Comment: @JohnG. yes it does.

Comment: @sciona But can it be a general rule, that when we have such cases with, let's say, the same $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan{a_n}$, that the whole series will always converge whenever what's inside arctan converges , yes ?

Comment: @JohnG. no it depends on $a_n$, the fact that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and $\tan^{-1} \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as well leads to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{n}$ to converge by Liebniz Criteria in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small $z$, $\arctan z$ behaves exactly like $z$:
$$\arctan z = z+O(z^3) $$
hence $\sum_{n\geq 1}\arctan\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges by Leibniz' test. By the way,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\arctan\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=\operatorname{Arg}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)}=-0.506671\ldots$$

Comment: Dear God artillery to kill flies!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Recall that, for $x$ near $0$,
$$
\arctan x=x+\mathcal{O}\left(x^3\right)
$$
then
$$
\sum\arctan{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}=\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\sum\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)
$$ is **convergent** being the sum of two convergent series.